# How can I fix missing title tags and duplicate URLs on RSS and form pages in a Magento store?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, magento

It is a Magneto store and I see the following in Webmaster tools. How Can I fix missing title tags and duplicate URLs?

[image]

Comment: Not everything you see in Google Webmaster Tools is something you should fix or needs to be fixed. Two of the four in your image are repeats. Of the other two, I do not think you have to worry about a title so much. Personally, I would not worry about it. But, you can still wait for an answer and fix these if you would like.